# Does OWSLib have spatial filters?

Tags: python, wfs, owslib

I am trying to apply spatial filter on a WFS layer, but owslib.fes has only BBox spatial filter. Other spatial filters such as Intersects, Disjoint, Contains etc. are missing and unable to find.
I want to apply ***intersect*** filter. I am able to do it in ***GeoServer***.

Curl Request.

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:text/xml" --data @intersect.xml "https://demo.geo-solutions.it:443/geoserver/wfs"
```

@intersect.xml file.

```
       <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
             outputFormat="JSON"
          xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
          xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
          xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
          xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                              http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
         <wfs:Query typeName="geosolutions:Linee_in_america">
            <Filter>
              <Intersects>
                <PropertyName>the_geom</PropertyName>
                  <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                    <gml:coordinates>-74.817265,40.5296504</gml:coordinates>
                  </gml:Point>
                </Intersects>
              </Filter>
          </wfs:Query>
        <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states">
            <Filter>
              <Intersects>
                <PropertyName>the_geom</PropertyName>
                  <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                    <gml:coordinates>-74.817265,40.5296504</gml:coordinates>
                  </gml:Point>
                </Intersects>
              </Filter>
          </wfs:Query>
        </wfs:GetFeature>
```

Is it possible to implement this using OWSLib??

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#standards-support: `OWSLib currently only support filter building for WFS 1.1 (FE.1.1).` So OWSLib **does** support FE 1.1 filters and there is also an example about how to use PropertyIsLike filter. The challenge is to find the right syntax for the Intersects filter but once you get it right it should work. Maybe you can simple save the xml as you have it and use it like `wfs11.getfeature(typename='bvv:gmd_ex', filter=filterxml)`.

```
>>> from owslib.fes import *
>>> from owslib.etree import etree
>>> from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
>>> wfs11 = WebFeatureService(url='http://geoserv.weichand.de:8080/geoserver/wfs', version='1.1.0')

>>> filter = PropertyIsLike(propertyname='bez_gem', literal='Ingolstadt', wildCard='*')
>>> filterxml = etree.tostring(filter.toXML()).decode("utf-8")
>>> response = wfs11.getfeature(typename='bvv:gmd_ex', filter=filterxml)
```

Comment: I have seen it and following the same example but there isn't any spatial filter.

Comment: Filter is a generic term. Spatial filters are filters as well as property filters. They are used in the same way in WFS. Just use what you have as <filter> in @intersect.xml file.

Comment: By spatial filter I mean there is no  spatial operator. For example PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, PropertyIsLike are the operators. There is'nt any operator for spatial filtering, i.e intersects.

Comment: I think to create the filterxml for intersect, the respective operator is required. Can we create filterxml for intersect from whatever is available?

Comment: I do not quite get what you mean, sorry. Spatial filters compare reference geometry with the geometry field of the feature type. Why do you think that the filter that works directly against GeoServer is not usable in OWSLib? You can also look at the MapServer examples https://mapserver.org/ogc/filter_encoding.html?.  There is an intersects example as well, the filter used in it should work as filterxml.

Comment: Intersect is obviously available with WFS, this is what I have shown. My question is to apply intersect using OWSLib. It does not have any spatial operator just like the PropertyIsLike.

Comment: In simple words I need Intersect operator like PropertyIsLike operator.

Comment: For me it seems that PropertyIsLike is for convenience and what is really used is the output of filter.toXML().  Make a test, capture the xml formatted filter and use it in the code without PropertyIsLike. It should work.

Comment: I am looking for the intersect operator, that will create the formatted xml in the same way as PropertyIsLike does, which can further be passed to getfeature as filter. Owslib has only BBox operator for now and this is all the question was about.

Comment: That's right, Owslib does not currently help you with writing the xml. There is code dealing with spatial operands in https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/blob/master/owslib/fes.py and an open feature request in https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/issues/128. Meanwhile write the correctly formatted xml filter by other means and tell owslib to use that.